# Testing async tasks with robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

Do you know how to implement unit testing for AsyncTasks using Robolectric ? Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 18):

Call `execute(...)` on the task, then to wait for the result call `Robolectric.runBackgroundTasks()`/`Robolectric.flushBackgroundThreadScheduler()` then you can assert.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    //create task
    MyAsyncTask asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask();

    //start task
    asyncTask.execute(...);

    //wait for task code
    // Robolectric.runBackgroundTasks(); (pre 3.0)
    Robolectric.flushBackgroundThreadScheduler(); //from 3.0

    //can run asserts on result now
    assert...(asyncTask.get());
}
```

Comment: I keep getting an error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: this action is not supported in PAUSED mode." when doing this. Robolectric version: 4.6.1, running on SDK 30.

Comment: @OliverMetz Ask a new question.

Answer (score 7):

With Robolectric 2.4 this is now in `ShadowApplication`:

`ShadowApplication.runBackgroundTasks();`